# Is there a safety hazard when lock on grips are not pushed fully on to the handlebar?

Tags: handlebars, grips, flatbar

Recently got new single lock on grips (Ergon GA2 Fat) and I am trying to understand if the warning in the manual is referring to some real hazard or is just there because the legal department said so. The warning ([page 3, step 4](https://www.ergonbike.com/infocenter/downloads/ERG_MAN_GA2_07_2017.pdf#page=3)) says:

> Ensure that the grip is completely pushed on to the bar. Failure to do so will create a
> safety issue.

While I could push the grips all the way on to the bar, that feels to narrow for me.
My current lock on grips have an "overhang" of approximately 1 cm. Here is a crude illustration (the grip is the hatched, rounded rectangle):

[image]

I have used the bike like this for the past 2-3 years without any problem, however, now that I read above warning I am wondering if this is safe.

Is there an acceptable amount of overhang, or is any overhang cause for concern, as the manual states?

#### Background info

In finding out my bike fit in the past, I narrowed my handlebars by cutting of 2 cm on each side. Later I found that the narrowing was too much, so I simply shifted everything back a cm or so, creating this overhang.

80% of my riding happens as part of my day-to-day travels in an urban environment at moderate speeds, 20% of the time I use it as a road bike on tarmac. The bike is a Merida Speeder 200 with a straight handlebar and Shimano Sora SL-R3000 trigger shifters.

Comment: Does the *auto-stop* they are referring to on page 3, step 4 go over the handlebar slightly, or it simply contacts the side of it when fully pushed?

Comment: It contacts the side when fully pushed.

Comment: Consider getting the correct width handlebars. May save you some hassle in the long run, and budget ones aren't crazy expensive, especially if you sell the existing bars to recuperate some cost.

Answer (score 4):

Lock-on grips like those stay solidly on the handlebar because of the friction of their clamp and not because of the friction of their body like traditional rubber grips, so the fact that there is 1 cm less contact surface would not change much in this regard.

The manufacturer, of course, states in the manual that this can cause safety issues for their own protection, but also because they probably did not test how secure the grips were for different "overhang" lengths. The vast majority of users would simply push them all the way in as it is intended so there is no value for them to qualify the safety of other "configurations".

If the "overhang" was longer though, this could put pressure on the grips and I guess they could start to weaken at the bending point. It would also not provide a solid handle as a significant part of it would not be supported by the handlebar.